# Undefined symbol error for base class in C++ shared library

Tags: c++, compilation, linker-errors, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

I compiled the following code as a shared library using `g++ -shared ...`:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {}
  virtual ~Foo() = 0;
  virtual int Bar() = 0;
};

class TestFoo : public Foo {
public:
  int Bar() { return 0; }
};

extern "C" {
  Foo* foo;
  void init() {
    // Runtime error: undefined symbol: _ZN3FooD2Ev
    foo = new TestFoo(); // causes error
  }
  void cleanup() { delete(foo); }
  void bar() { foo->Bar(); }
}
```

The point is to expose the functionality of my classes (here just minimal toy classes as an example) as a simple `C` API with the three functions `init`, `cleanup`, and `bar`.

When I try to load the shared library (using `dyn.load` in `R`) I get an error:

```
unable to load shared library 'test.so':
test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3FooD2Ev
```

So, it seems it cannot find the `Foo` constructor. What am I doing wrong and how can this be fixed?

*UPDATE*: Thanks, jbar! So it was the `Foo` *de*structor. Could I have known this from the cryptic symbol in the error message: `_ZN3FooD2Ev`? Does the `D` in `FooD` stand for destructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can't declare pure virtual destructor. Even if a virtual destructor is declared as pure, it will have to implement an empty body (at least) for the destructor.

Comment: How would such a body be implemented? If I implement it for the base class `g++` complains about a redefinition.

Comment: Can you please post the explicit code solution? Is it  `virtual ~Foo() {}`?

Answer (score 18):

> UPDATE: So it was the Foo destructor. Could I have known this from the cryptic symbol in the error message: _ZN3FooD2Ev? Does the D in FooD stand for destructor?

You can use the program c++filt.

So c++filt _ZN3FooD2Ev returns "Foo::~Foo()".

Comment: Wow, I wish I would have known about this years ago. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Regardring your update, "_ZN3FooD2Ev" is "Foo::~Foo()" [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Check out the "demangle" program.